# Как запустить java telegram bot'a на openshift?

Tags: java, maven, telegram, бот, openshift

В общем, создал бота на java, maven работает, все ок. Но при попытке deploy'a толку нет. Программа как бы не запускается. В чем может быть проблема? Какие файлы для запуска нужно добавить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. создать проект
2. Добавляем  Red Hat OpenJDK 8 java xpaas
3. Что бы проект запускался нужно настроить сборку в pom.xml

   ```
   <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <phase>package</phase>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>single</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
               <configuration>
                   <descriptorRefs>
                       <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                   </descriptorRefs>
                   <archive>
                       <manifest>
                       <mainClass>ua.kharkiv.gvg.BotConfig</mainClass> <!-- Нужно указать главный класс -->
                      </manifest>
                   </archive>
                   <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
               </configuration>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
   </build>
   ```

пример Ехобот [github](https://github.com/GVGUAD/uipabot)